# basic scaling math equation help needed

Tags: math

im having trouble figuring out a math problem that im trying to implement.

so at 0 scrolling on a page, i want the background to be at opacity 0.5
and at scroll position of a window height on a page, i want the background to be at opacity 1.0

so on opening a webpage, jQuery will get the height of the page, let's say it gets a value of 700 pixels.

When the screen is scrolled to position 350, i want the background to be at opacity 0.75

Summary:

at scroll position 0, background is at 0.5

at scroll position 350, background is at 0.75

at scroll position 700, background is at 1.0

What is a math equation I can use to attain this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `0.5` minimum, and `1.0` is the maximum, then your equation will look something like:

```
opacity = 0.5 + 0.5 * scroll_position / page_height
```

A couple quick checks:

```
0.5 + 0.5 * 0 / 700 = 0.5

0.5 + 0.5 * 700 / 700 = 1.0

0.5 + 0.5 * 350 / 700 = 0.75
```

---

You can think of the equation as being in two halves:

The first half is the minimum `0.5`, which is fixed.

The second half has to give a maximum of another `0.5`, in which case the result would be `1.0`.  In this case, we want a full `0.5` if the `scroll_position` is as much as the `page_height`, and if `scroll_position` is lower, then we should only return a fraction of `0.5`.  This means we just want to take the ratio of the two, by performing the division and then multiplying by the maximum:

```
0.5 * scroll_position / page_height
```

Comment: perfect! thanks so much! I knew it was a simple equation!